# Proper binding of a native library in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, java-native-interface

Given this method in a `c++` library ([Gifflen, animated gif maker](https://github.com/wasabeef/gifflen-sample)):

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_jiggawatt_giffle_Giffle_Init(JNIEnv *ioEnv, jobject ioThis, 
jstring gifName, jint w, jint h, jint numColors, jint quality, jint frameDelay) { ... }
```

And this signature to access it:

```
extern "C"
{
    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_jiggawatt_giffle_Giffle_Init(JNIEnv *ioEnv,
    jobject ioThis, jstring gifName, jint w, jint h, jint numColors, jint quality, 
    jint frameDelay);
}
```

Shouldn't the p/invoke be similar to that?

```
[DllImport("libgifflen.so", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int Java_org_jiggawatt_giffle_Giffle_Init(string gifName, int w, 
int h, int numColors, int quality, int frameDelay);
```

I have a program that basically just tries to access that Init methods.

I'm loading the library successfully: `Java.Lang.JavaSystem.LoadLibrary("gifflen");`

Then it seems I'm pointing to the correct method, but it crashes as soon as it enters in the method.

I'm calling Init with same values as in the java demo application (and with basically the same values as in all my other implementations of this gif encoder since this is the same code-base for all libraries):

```
var pathForResult = "/storage/sdcard0/giftest/giffleResult.gif";
int optCol = 256, optQuality = 100, optDelay = 4;
Giffle.Init (pathForResult , 256, 256, optCol, optQuality, optDelay);
```

Then I'm getting this crash:

```
[mono-rt]   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper managed-to-native) org.jiggawatt.giffle.Giffle.Java_org_jiggawatt_giffle_Giffle_Init (string,int,int,int,int,int) <IL 0x00046, 0xffffffff>
[mono-rt]   at org.jiggawatt.giffle.Giffle.Init (string,int,int,int,int,int) [0x00001] in c:\Users\user.name\Projects\Giffle\Giffle\Giffle.cs:20
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt]   Attempting native Android stacktrace:
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt]   at Java_org_jiggawatt_giffle_Giffle_Init+19 [0x6433c83c]
[mono-rt]   at ???+12272 [0x6467fff0]
[libc] Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x6f7475d3 (code=1), thread 29670 (myapp.someapp)
```

I'm I using native libraries incorrectly in my Xamarin application?

> Code for bindings

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace org.jiggawatt.giffle
{
    public class Giffle {

        public const string GIFFLE_DLL_NAME = "libgifflen.so";

        [DllImport(GIFFLE_DLL_NAME, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern int Java_org_jiggawatt_giffle_Giffle_Init(string gifName, int w, int h, int numColors, int quality, int frameDelay);

        [DllImport(GIFFLE_DLL_NAME, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern void Java_org_jiggawatt_giffle_Giffle_Close();

        [DllImport(GIFFLE_DLL_NAME, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern int Java_org_jiggawatt_giffle_Giffle_AddFrame(int[] inArray);
    }
}
```

> Code for test

```
var external = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
var appPath = System.IO.Path.Combine (external, "giftest");
if (!Directory.Exists (appPath)) {
    Directory.CreateDirectory (appPath);
}

var t = "/storage/sdcard0/giftest/result3.gif";

File.Delete (t);
int optCol = 256, optQuality = 100, optDelay = 4;

Giffle.Init (t, 256, 256, optCol, optQuality, optDelay);
var image = Bitmap.CreateBitmap (256, 256, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    image = Bitmap.CreateBitmap (256, 256, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
    image.EraseColor (Color.Argb (255, 255 - i * 4, i * 4, i * 4));

    int[] pixelsCopy = new int[image.Width * image.Height];
    image.LockPixels ();
    image.GetPixels(pixelsCopy, 0, image.Width, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
    image.UnlockPixels ();
    image.Recycle ();
    Giffle.Java_org_jiggawatt_giffle_Giffle_AddFrame (pixelsCopy);
}

Giffle.Java_org_jiggawatt_giffle_Giffle_Close ();
```

Comment: You can not skip the "JNIEnv *ioEnv, jobject ioThis" part of the calling signature. Have you looked at the Xamarin San Angeles NDK sample? https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/SanAngeles_NDK/

Comment: Oh, ok. I can't skip the JNI parameters. I thought there was some internal resolution of JNI stuff.

Comment: @LéonPelletier did you end up finding an answer to this? I'm also getting a crash and have a similar binding setup to you.

Comment: Do you also have a problem in understanding how to pass this JniEnv object like in my case? I haven't made similar code recently, and I didn't keep anything source controlled nor have I this anymore on my hard drive, so I can't verify if I've solved that. While writing this comment, I've found this SO question which can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429213/what-is-jobject-this-in-jni-and-what-is-it-used-for. It seems like there are some ugly conventions to follow in method signature in order to use the bridge between your code and java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only skip this arguments "JNIEnv *ioEnv, jobject ioThis" like you do in java if your c++ code does nothing with this arguments, otherwise you should also include this arguments in your function definition. And you should not use C# types, use java types instead.

```
[DllImport("libgifflen.so", EntryPoint = "Java_org_jiggawatt_giffle_Giffle_Init", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int Init(IntPtr env, IntPtr thiz, IntPtr gifName, IntPtr w, 
IntPtr h, IntPtr numColors, IntPtr quality, IntPtr frameDelay);
```

Call your function like this:

```
Init(JNIEnv.Handle, System.IntPtr.Zero, (new Java.Lang.String("Your gif name")).Handle, (new Java.Lang.Integer(w)).Handle,
    (new Java.Lang.Integer(h)).Handle, (new Java.Lang.Integer(numColors)).Handle, (new Java.Lang.Integer(quality)).Handle, (new Java.Lang.Integer(frameDelay)).Handle);
```

Check also this answer:

[Load .so file in Xamarin.Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433520/load-so-file-in-xamarin-android/49743686#49743686)