# JNI "jobject thiz" and jboolean parameters relationship

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a `JNI` code like this:

```
  class NativeConnector {
    public static native getKey(boolean isValid);
  }


  JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL 
  Java_com_mg_helper_NativeConnector_getKey(JNIEnv *env, jboolean is_valid) {
      if (is_valid) {
         return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "48759d35c");
      } else {
         return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "527c4f704");
      }
   }
```

The problem is that `is_valid` in `JNI` is always `true` and result is always `"48759d35c"`, although I send `false` in method `getKey`

```
   NativeConnector.getKey(false) // result is "48759d35c"
```

If I change `JNI` method with `jobject`, it can work well:

```
 JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL 
  Java_com_mg_helper_NativeConnector_getKey(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz , jboolean is_valid)
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14579268/719212), `jobject thiz` is referenced to an object of type (NativeConnector), and `jclass` is used for static method
So the question is, what is relationship between `jobject`, `jclass` and `jboolean` in this case? why is `jboolean` paramter always true if I don't use `jobject`?

Comment: any comment for voting down?

Comment: I can't speak for anybody else, but I find it amazing that you even tried what you tried.

Comment: @EJP it's just because I don't know the root cause of my problem. So it's the reason I'm here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that `is_valid` in JNI is always true

The problem is that your JNI method signature is incorrect.

> why is `jboolean` parameter always true if I don't use `jobject`?

Because not using the `jobject` parameter is wrong. You're receiving the `jobject` argument into the `jboolean` parameter. The correct method signature for

```
class NativeConnector {
    public static native getKey(boolean isValid);
}
```

is

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_mg_helper_NativeConnector_getKey(JNIEnv *env, jobject *thiz, jboolean is_valid);
```

Whatever process you used to derive the signature `Java_com_mg_helper_NativeConnector_getKey(JNIEnv *env, jboolean is_valid)` should be thrown away. Use `javah` to generate your method signatures. It is never wrong.

Comment: I can see how the OP thought the thiz wasn't needed because it's a static method, being called in a static way; by Class.method. Apparently, Java still manages to pull a "thiz" object from a hat.

Answer (score 0):

a typo in @user207421 answer.

for static methods,
public static native getKey(boolean isValid);

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_mg_helper_NativeConnector_getKey(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jboolean is_valid);

Perhaps early javah use jobject in the second param, just
jdk8 javah use jclass